# An image of Google map is showing up in the background of my website pages when viewed on mobile Safari

Tags: mobile-safari

All of a sudden an image of Google maps is showing up in the background of my blog pages when viewed on a mobile phone, both iPhone and Android. It doesn't show up on the main blog page, but on the individual blog post pages. So for instance if you view https://farragio.com/blog.php on your phone you won't see the map, but if you view a specific blog page on your phone, such as https://farragio.com/blog/skin-benefits-of-avocado-oil, you will most likely see the map, or at the very least will see a map search bar at the top left corner of the page. I need help figuring out where it's coming from and how to get rid of it.

I've tried clearing Safari history on my phone, as well as looking at the web pages on other phones, but nothing has changed.

[Screenshot from phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb1ky.png)

Comment: You have a `section` and a`div` at the end of your page. Search for "google-map animated" and you will find it. If you used any CMS or website builder, check if that is not included by default or if you have any plugin adding that. It is hard to tell without much more information. Did you build the website by yourself? What tools did you use?

Comment: Bear with me because I'm only a novice when it comes to code. When I view the page source I do not find "google-map animated" or even just "map". Are you seeing it somewhere else besides page source?

I'm using an online service to build the website, but do include my own coding on some parts. The map only just started showing up in the last week and I'm not aware of changing or adding any code that would have caused it.

Comment: I think I may have finally figured it out and it's the Responsive/Mobile Plus setting on my website service. When I remove Mobile Plus the map doesn't show up now.

Comment: Yes, you will only see the code if you resize your browser window to simulate a mobile screen and then refresh the page. Looks like this setting is inserting the map there. It appears that it should insert the map on the bottom of the page, but maybe their system is broken or your custom code is breaking the positioning.

Comment: Glad to know you found the issue though. You are welcome to share here your custom code to see if anything could be affecting the position of the map. Another suggestion is to contact the support of this online service and see if they can help you (in case you wants to include the map)